# Magento 1.7 Admin Login Fatal error: Call to a member function getBlockName() on a non-object in line 43

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, fatal-error

Can someone help me?

On `index.php/admin` the following exception was thrown:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getBlockName() on a non-object in /home/ahorraen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Block/Captcha.php on line 43
```

Comment: Please post the code if you want to get an answer.

Answer (score 14):

Delete var/cache and var/session

This works for me!

Comment: @SameerSingh This did not fix my problem

Comment: @SameerSingh This fixed my problem

Answer (score 2):

Clearing the cache works for me.

Just remove var/cache/All folders

Even after removing it may take few minutes to get refreshed.

Comment: You mean all folders under `var/cache`? If that is the case then this answer doesn't really provide new information.

Answer (score 1):

Only `cache/` and `session/` don't work for me.
Set properly chmod write permissions of folders

```
var
var/cache
var/session
```

Comment: what does "Set properly" mean. Are there specific values it should be set to? If not, how will someone reading this answer know what values to set?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that would cause this, such as incorrectly overwriting the `admin/captcha/type` field in a community or local module. However, this is most likely to be an issue with the cache as others suggested. Make sure that you clear all caches that you have, including Memcached, Redis and/or APC.

See my answer over here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25902858/1038564

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the cache and session files did not do it for me, but I did find that the website ids were not set correctly for some reason in the core_website table.  Once set correctly, all was fine.

Comment: When importing MySQL-dumps with "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0", take care your dump contains LOCK-Statements, otherwise Auto-Incements would become messed up, sometimes changing the storeID of Admin to some number above zero, resulting in the aforementioned error.

Answer (score 0):

Could be because of a module you recently disabled through XML. Was the case here:

```
/app/etc/modules
```

Or through the backend.

You can change to your magento directory and do the following in shell:

```
cd /yourdirectory/
find -type -f -mtime 1
```

Change 1 to 30 for last 30 days...

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Those are  the directories of the Magento installation.