# magento backend unable to login Fatal error getBlockName

Tags: magento

Running on Magento 1.8

I was copying to a test production site but at the backend I couldn't login and this is the error message.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getBlockName() on a non-object in /var/www/test/app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Block/Captcha.php on line 43
```

To solve this problem usually we delete `var/cache` folder, but the problem is on this test site we don't have a `var` folder so I'm not sure what is causing the error.

Here is the [link](https://www.nubex.my/test/index.php/admin)

Comment: Usually, not having a writable var/ folder is a fatal error all its own that will halt Magento in its tracks. Gotta have one somewhere to write temporary files. Just ran into that issue yesterday in fact. No where to write var/report files so I couldn't even find out what was wrong till I kludged it to display the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code assumes a block class exists and uses instance of that class and then calls a functions `getBlockName()`.

```
class Mage_Captcha_Block_Captcha extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    /**
     * Renders captcha HTML (if required)
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $blockPath =     Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($this->getFormId())->getBlockName();
```

is the code thats creating issues.

If you look into this line : `getCaptcha($this->getFormId())`

this should have returned a block instance but for some reason it didn't.

So you need to check your Magento logs and debug as to why `getCaptcha($this->getFormId())`  didn't generate a block.

Comment: Hi may I know where can I find the logs folder? Thanks

Comment: Well when captcha is executed some images will be created.So it needs whatever are required as per Magento.Without var folder where will your log and cache or all temporary things go.Do crate var folder and make sure permissions are proper this will probably solve your bug.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was that `Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($this->getFormId())` was not returning a class like it should have. It turned out that `app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Helper/Data.php` method `getCaptcha` wasn't returning a model because `$this->getConfigNode('type')` was returning `NULL`. This turned out to be an issue with my cache. We use both file cache in `var/cache` as well as Redis. Once I cleared all caches, this problem went away.

By the way, `$this->getConfigNode('type')` tries to get the config value for either `admin/captcha/type` or `customer/captcha/type`, neither of which are you going to find in the `core_config_data` table in the database. These are actually set in `app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc/config.xml`.